# cache for a dynamic css file in php

Tags: php, css, caching

I have a **style.php** file with some variables that allow the admin to change some colors

In the style.php file I have added the **cache** in this way:

```
<?php 
$variables = array('#CCC','#800'); // from db
header('Cache-control: max-age=86400, public, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s',time()+86400).' GMT');
header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s',filemtime('style.php')).' GMT');
?>
body{ background: <?php echo $variables[0]; ?>; }
```

Everything works, cache too, except that when a user change a variable the style.php is not realoaded (but always cached).

It seems that the error is the **last-modified header** in: **filemtime('style.php')** that tell the browser to reload the CSS only when this file is **phisically edited**...

Is possible to tell the browser to reload the style.css when the **CONTENT** is changed? for example when the `$variabile[0]` changes from `#CCC` to `#FFF`?

Answer (score 0):

This might be kind of a weird way to do it, but the only thing I can think of off the top of my head.

Create versioning by updating a version number whenever the style is update, then append it as a querystring

In your style.php:

```
<?php
    $variables = array('#CCC','#800'); // or whatever is pulled from your db
?>

body{ background: <?php echo $variables[0]; ?>; }
```

And in your actual page

```
<?php
    $version = 'pulled from your db'; // this would be a number, updated whenever values change

    // somewhere in your head
    <link type="text/css" href="style.php?v=<php print $version; ?>" />
?>
```

This way, each version is cached separately, but will reset with the variable change. You shouldn't need to do all the header setting you're doing either, this alone should suffice.

Just an idea. Heads up, this won't work with stone age browsers like IE6 ... they don't cache anything at all with a querystring.